# opencv imshow and imwrite give realloc error

Tags: c++, opencv, ogre

I have an OGRE::Image img object whose PixelFormat is PF_BYTE_RGBA, I convert it to cv::Mat with following code

```
cv::Mat modelImage;
modelImage.create(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), CV_8UC3);

int copyChannels[6] = {0,2,1,1,2,0};
cv::Mat ogre2mat(img.getHeight(), img.getWidth(), CV_8UC4, img.getData());
mixChannels(&ogre2mat, 1, &modelImage, 1, copyChannels, 3);
```

Now, this prints the values perfectly :

```
cout << modelImage.row(0) << endl;
```

But one of the following code give realloc() error

```
 imwrite("img.png",modelImage);
 imshow("img",modelImage);
```

Also, I get following as output from valgrind. Looks like some error on Qt

```
==28986== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==28986== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==28986== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==28986== Command: ./run diver.urdf    
==28986== 
==28986== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==28986==    at 0x4C2CE8E: realloc (in     /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28986==    by 0xFA26E3D: QListData::realloc(int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1)
==28986==    by 0xFA26EF9: QListData::append(int) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1)
==28986==    by 0xFB13D8B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1)
==28986==    by 0xFB0FE28: qRegisterResourceData(int, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*, unsigned char const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1)
==28986==    by 0xF9B2EB2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5.2.1)
==28986==    by 0x4010139: call_init.part.0 (dl-init.c:78)
==28986==    by 0x4010222: _dl_init (dl-init.c:36)
==28986==    by 0x4001309: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so)
==28986==    by 0x1: ???
==28986==    by 0xFFEFFFE02: ???
==28986==    by 0xFFEFFFE08: ???
==28986==  Address 0xbf7e840 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "_ZN9QListData11shared_nullE"
==28986== 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
==28986== 
==28986== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28986==     in use at exit: 73,525 bytes in 636 blocks
==28986==   total heap usage: 1,557 allocs, 921 frees, 117,760 bytes allocated
==28986== 
==28986== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28986==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28986==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28986==      possibly lost: 14,005 bytes in 300 blocks
==28986==    still reachable: 59,520 bytes in 336 blocks
==28986==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28986== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==28986== 
==28986== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==28986== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Aborted
```

Comment: Given the `Qt5`-related stuff I'd say the problem is with `imshow`. Does this command work in any other (simpler) context?

Answer (score 0):

I followed following steps and it worked.

1) I uninstalled the opencv libary.

2) Downloaded the version 2.4.10

3) Installed the dependencies as shown in

http://robotics.jacobs-university.de/TMP/kaustubh/vision/install_opencv_latest.txt

3) Then followed both the approaches described in http://www.aichengxu.com/view/52596 (It is in Chinese, google translate will help). I updated Gstreamer with

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
```

But it did not work.

5) Second approach worked. So I set

```
WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10=OFF
```

and

```
WITH_QT=OFF
```

in

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON  WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10 = OFF ..
```

Then,

```
make && make install
```

Basically, the error was something to do with Qt.